# LWJGL 3 : GLFW Inputs don't work

Tags: java, input, lwjgl

I'm just starting a new project on LWJGL 3 and so I've tested the example project here : http://www.lwjgl.org/guide.
I've set up the project, added the library, natives... 
And when I launched the program everything worked fine except the input which didn't respond. (The window should close when you press ESC.)
I tried all possibilities of handling the input but it didn't work in any case...
I thank you very much in advance for you help.

Comment: There's an [issue with GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/548) that might be related to your problem. It seems to have been [fixed in LWJGL by using older builds](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5861.0).

Comment: I've just tried it and it worked ! (I used the stable version instead of the release) Thank you very much sir !